How to have 'emacs' behave like 'find-file' within vterm?
I know that such a thing is possible within eshell; however, I am now using vterm, and I'd like for when I type emacs for it to be as if I typed find-file.
For example, for eshell, you could do
alias emacs for i in ${eshell-flatten-list $*} {find-file $i}


M-x server-start and then use emacsclient in your terminal instead of emacs.
